# How can i remove the remote object from the RMI runtime

Tags: java, rmi, remote-server, remoteobject

When i shutdown the RMI server program by using, 
`serverReg.unbind("LibraryServer");` it only remove the bound of remote object and it's key '`LibraryServer`. If i start the server same time it give me an exception `ObjID already in use`. How can i entirety remove remote object from the registry ?.
Binding statement of Remote object and it's key is,

```
serverReg.rebind("LibraryServer", new RemoteFactoryImpl());
```

Comment: Can you please explain little more.. Your code seems good. What is you expectation.

Comment: Simply, i need start my server after shutdown it many times. For the first time i started server and shutted down it works fine. After shuted down the server and try to start it again with same port and same remote object and same key `LibraryServer` it gave me that exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I shutdown the RMI server program by using, serverReg.unbind("LibraryServer"); it only remove the [binding] of remote object and it's key 'LibraryServer.

Correct.

> If i start the server same time it give me an exception ObjID already in use.

I'd like to see that exception and stack trace.

> How can I entirety remove remote object from the registry?

You have already done so. You may be looking for a way to *unexport* the remote object, which is given by `UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject()`.

However the `ObjID already in use` error can realistically only be coming from trying to export another *Registry* from a JVM in which you have already exported one. Which doesn't correspond with your description at all.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i found an answer for that, `unbined` method only removes connection between remote object and its key. So cannot restart the rmi server with same remote object because first remote object still in the registry. By using `unexportObject` method of `UnicastRemoteObject` class can be entirely remove remote object from registry. I found it from a post of [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject).

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(serverReg, false);
```

Comment: You've misunderstood. `unbind()` removes the object from the Registry. `unexportObject()` unexports the object. They aren't the same thing.